# Insert unknown number of values

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have a table *import_saved_format_det* (call it A) structured as followed:

```
row_id | hdr_id | column_name
1      | 1      | supplier_name
2      | 1      | branch_name
3      | 2      | supplier_name
4      | 2      | branch_name
5      | 2      | barcode
```

The number of *column_name*'s for a given *hdr_id* is unknown but always 5 or less.

I have another table called *traxs_temp..__SimpleImport_ColumnNames* (call it B) structured as followed:

```
row_id | session_id | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5
```

with field1 to field5 nullable.

In a stored procedure I want to INSERT the *column_name*'s from A for a given *hdr_id* in the table B. My problem is that I don't know how many *column_name* I have to insert in advance.

Here is what I did so far

```
DECLARE @hdr_id int = 1
DECLARE @session_id varchar(30) = 'test'

DECLARE @list varchar(max) = ''
SELECT @list = @list + '[' + column_name + '],' FROM import_saved_format_det WHERE hdr_id = @hdr_id
SELECT @list = REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(@list), 1, 1, ''))

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO traxs_temp..__SimpleImport_ColumnNames
                (session_id, 
                field1, 
                field2, 
                field3, 
                field4,
                field5)
            SELECT 
                @session_id,
                * 
            FROM 
                (
                    SELECT column_name FROM import_saved_format_det WHERE hdr_id = @hdr_id
                ) src PIVOT ( MAX(column_name) FOR column_name IN (' + @list  + ') ) piv;'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql, N'@hdr_id int, @session_id varchar(30)', @hdr_id, @session_id
```

But I'm getting **The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list.**

Is there a way to set the remaining *field*'s to null? Or am I thinking this wrong?

Comment: I don't understand people downvoting without writing a comment. What's worth a downvote here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *Joe C*'s answer, I found a way of doing what I wanted. I added a few more lines when building the list for my PIVOT to add as many dummies as necessary.

```
DECLARE @list varchar(max) = ''
SELECT @list = @list + '[' + column_name + '],' FROM import_saved_format_det WHERE hdr_id = @hdr_id
SELECT @fields_count = LEN(@list) - LEN(REPLACE(@list, ',', ''))
SELECT @list = @list + '[dummy' + CONVERT(varchar, range.x) + '],' FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) range(x) WHERE range.x BETWEEN @fields_count + 1 AND 5 
SELECT @list = REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(@list), 1, 1, ''))
```

So for *hdr_id = 2* I get **[supplier_name],[branch_name],[barcode],[dummy4],[dummy5]**

Answer (score 1):

I have only ever been able to do that if I have a primary key with Identity.  I could leave out the column names and do something like Insert Table1 Select a,b,c From Table2 where Table1 has a fourth column that is a primary key (Identity).

I suggest that when building @list you determine how many columns you have and tack on dummy values for the remaining columns.  For example for character fields you can tack on '', ''...

Comment: Thanks for the last paragraph, it helped me finding a way around.

Comment: I am very happy i could help, this site has helped me many times.